# Создание экземпляров System.Web.UI.UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Задача создавать программно экземпляры объектов класса `UserControl` для заполнения ими таблицы `GridView`.

Допустим есть класс `MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl`
В конструкторе инициализирую его элементы управления `Button1 = new Button()` и т.д.

```
MyControl control = new MyControl();
```

Не работает, объект создается, но не отображается, `Visible = true` не помогает.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Не забывайте, что в WebForms контролы - это всего лишь фикция, на их основе строится html-разметка. Во что должен превратиться ваш контрол? Может стоит просто сделать шаблон разметки и заполнить его своими данными?

Comment: В данный момент я так и делаю, у меня просто на страницу добавлен контрол в поле TemplateField, но мне не нравится что это 1 объект, есть много проблем с передачей данных, использованием событий и т.д.

Comment: возможно, стоило ваш контрол задать потомком/содержимым чему-либо?

Comment: mainGrid.Children.Add(control); К сожалению подобный метод пробовал, но проблему это естественно не решило, т.к. нужно в данный контрол передавать индекс для запроса в бд. Пока у меня это передается при загрузке страницы и работает корректно, но я не могу нормально использовать события нажатия тех же кнопок, т.к. это 1 объект. 
Возможно есть какие-то методы создания копий того же контрола?

Comment: По идее =) `new MyControl();` каждый раз возвращает новый экземпляр класса `MyControl` (_копии_, ага), т.е. создали _копию_, задали ей свойства (в т.ч. сгенерировали имя конкретной _копии_ и задали ей обработчик нажатия какой требуется), закинули в список потомков кому-то, [повторить];

Из множества потомков выбрать по имени Linq'ом, например.

Может, я плохо понял, но вроде ничего невозможного.

Comment: Если есть возможность, покажите простейший пример, т.к. перековырял уже уйму простыней кода в справке msdn, но толку от них мало. Сейчас попробовал наследовать еще и IClonable, кинул на страницу свой UserControl и скопировать его методом Clone(). Тоже не работает.

Comment: Если что, решил проблему альтернативным путем, но вопрос все же остался не раскрытым.